# How to show auto suggetion in Android Custom Key board

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-softkeyboard

i am Working on Android Custom keyboard application and i want to show auto correct suggestions  like in Image :- test Rest,Testing ..i am not getting how to do this i am using  Softkeybord  class

Here is image :-

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see your image? Edit: Welcome to SO, What have you tried so far?

Comment: i added but not showing